# Dividing by 2, a billion times

Tags: numerical-methods

Sorry this is a mathematically illiterate question! I'm coming from a philosophy background here.

Is there a way to find out what $100$ divided by $2$, a billion times over, would be?

As in $\frac{100} { 2} = 50, \frac{50} { 2} = 25$   etc for a billion divisions.

I don't know how to begin to do that kind of calculation, as far as I understand it's different to divide $100$ by $2^ {10^9}$... otherwise I'm lost!

Comment: @Haris Or $\dfrac{100}{2^{1000000000}}$.

Comment: Why would you even want to know that though?

Comment: "*I don't know how to begin to do that kind of calculation*", but at least you already know how to do the first two steps.

Comment: Are you looking for a decimal representation? What's the goal of the calculation?

Comment: You get *approximately* $2.1678 \times 10^{-301029994}$.  The exact decimal expansion has too many digits to post here.

Comment: The decadal logarithm is obviously
$$
\log_{10} \frac{100}{2^{10^9}} =
\log_{10} 100-\log_{10} 2^{10^9} =
2-10^9 \log_{10} 2 = -3.010299...  \times 10^{8}.
$$

Comment: If you want to find the decimal digits, it's probably easier to calculate $5^{10^9}$ (via say https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and shift the decimal point over $10^9 - 2$ places.